# find a web element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i have a problem to find an web element,

at - https://apk.support/apk-downloader
when searching -  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thehomedepot&hl=en&gl=US
the button - "Merge Apk"

the id "zipapk" don't work and not a Xpath

any one have an idea ?

the id "zipapk" don't work and not a Xpath
can't find it with CSS selector

Comment: Can you share your code trials in the question and error from the console?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge at hand pertains to the coexistence of multiple elements sharing the `'id' attribute 'zipapk,'` thereby causing some confusion during interaction.

To sort this out, my recommendation is to **use XPath with an index**.For Example,`(//a[@id='zipapk'])[1]` This helps you pinpoint the exact button you want to click on. Adding this extra detail makes your automation script more accurate and dependable.
This adjustment makes your script stronger, reducing the chances of problems when dealing with multiple elements sharing the same ID.

This is the code I have implemented to fulfill this purpose:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initialize Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://apk.support/apk-downloader")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Passing the Url to input field
Textbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='package']")
Textbox.send_keys("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thehomedepot&hl=en&gl=US ")

# Click on Analyse
Analysebutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@class='w-button']")
Analysebutton.click()

# wait for the Merge apk to load and click on it
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
mergeAPK = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//a[@id='zipapk'])[1]")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((mergeAPK)))
mergeAPK.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

If you wish to perform a hands-on test, I have created a test case using **Test Assist, a no-code Selenium editor**. I invite you to review and execute the test case by clicking on the following link:
https://app.testassist.dev/program/87bad2bb-df6a-4f50-8365-112908626fc7

Hope That Helps!